# How to shuffle pieces of large video files?

Tags: video, media-player

For a party we want to show film-fragments using a projector. We have around 50 full-length movie avis and would like to shuffle them in shorter pieces. So every ca. 2-5 minutes another piece should begin.

For example a sequence could be: Movie05-12m00s-14m30s, Movie08-55m50s-57m00s, Movie02-02m42s-06m40s, etc.

So, random movies, at random positions within the movie of random lengths.

What would be the kind of solution we're looking for? We were thinking 2 scenarios:

1. Before doing this use some kind of tool to cut all avis in smaller pieces and put them on shuffle in a regular media player
2. A sort of "VJ" program that can do this shuffle mixing realtime.

Any suggestions for any of the above scenarios?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Some free very good video editors:

[VideoPad Video Editor](http://www.nchsoftware.com/videopad/index.html)

> VideoPad makes editing your video
>   easy. This full featured video editor
>   lets you create professional looking
>   videos with transitions, music and
>   narration in just minutes. VideoPad is
>   also one of the fastest video stream
>   processors on the market today and is
>   available free.

[Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/)

> Avidemux is a free video editor
>   designed for simple cutting, filtering
>   and encoding tasks. It supports many
>   file types, including AVI, DVD
>   compatible MPEG files, MP4 and ASF,
>   using a variety of codecs. Tasks can
>   be automated using projects, job queue
>   and powerful scripting capabilities.

[VideoThang](http://www.videothang.com/)

> *simple editing controls*
>  Cut, trim, build. Easy. Want to cut out
>   your brother-in-law’s embarrassing
>   karaoke at the beginning of the video?
>   Done. Zoom in on the cute friend in
>   the group shot? Done. So easy, well,
>   even you could do it.

[VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/)
The swiss-knife of video editing (but not the simplest to use).

[Open Video Joiner](http://www.321slideshow.com/mp4-joiner.htm)
For putting the pieces together, also with transition effects.

Comment: I think the OP doesn't want to cut up 50+ video files manually.

Comment: @Johannes: Joining 50+ files is easy using Open Video Joiner. But cutting has to be done manually. Windows Movie Maker can more or less identify movie segments, but I didn't recommend it because of its codec limitations.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think it will be too much work to do it manually. Therefore, I don't see this as the answer yet.

Comment: @Gabriël: As I said above, if your videos are of the right format(s), Windows Movie Maker can automatically analyze segments from multiple sources which you can compile into one resulting video. If you need more capabilities than that, you're looking into professional and very pricey video-editing products. I've added above VideoThang, which completes the list of free and well-known video editors.